# error when defining a new vim syntax

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Why can't this line correctly highlight all things between `(*` and `*)` as comments in vim?

```
syn region   datsComment start="(\*" end="\*)" contains=datsComment,datsTodo
hi def link datsComment Comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does for me (in a fresh buffer without other syntax definitions). You probably have other syntax elements there that prevent a match.

You need to find out which syntax group causes that. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. If you find other syntax groups obscuring the match, you probably should include them in the `contains=datsComment,datsTodo,...` part.

Comment: `:syn list` shows `datsComment    xxx start=/(\*/ end=/\*)/  contains=datsComment,datsTodo` is this correct? seems a little different from my definition

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and you don't seem to have any other syntax definitions. Does SyntaxAttr show the syntax match in a test file?

Comment: Didn't get SyntaxAttr work, will try it later:) thanks~

Comment: I found out that there was a conflict with `rainbow parentheses`:) thanks~